# how to retrieve image using JSP dynamically from server's hard disk for a particular user

Tags: jsp

I am dealing with an application in which user uploads an image. The application takes the filename, edits it by appending the username for a particular user to it and then stores it in server's hard disk.

what i intend here is to load the particular image for the particular user. I plan to do this by using the session object. but still i am unable to find the solution.

So can you please provide a solution for retrieving/displaying the image using the session object for a particular user.
 you know i am new to maintaining sessions using JSP and storing session variables. I have written some code for it but i am afraid i am getting some errors in linking the code on jsfiddle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very generic, it would help if you paste some code of what you have done so far. Anyway here is a basic code that extract a USER_ID property from the session and link to an url which should return the image:

```
<%
//extract the property of the user session
String userId = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("USER_ID");
//build the image url
String imageUrl = "http://yourserver.com/yourimagefoler/"+userId+".jpg";
%>
<!--HTML code to show the image -->
<img src="<%=imageUrl%>" />
```

ps: USER_ID need to be set to the session object, also the imageURL need to be changed based in the folder that you save the image file

Comment: @fmodos...thanks,i have implemented your suggestion..but there is one problem, when the user uploads the image the first time, all the things go perfect like there is an entry in the database, the image is successfully stored... but after uploading when i retrieve the image in the jsp page, there is no image displayed.
But, if the same user logs in to his account, and asks for his image, the same page responds well and displays the image.
can u provide me with the solution???

Comment: i am attaching the my code here.... just replace the dynamic path with any static image path....and temp.jpg is a blank image with (100*98) dimensions...
the code-- http://jsfiddle.net/8nyzc/

Comment: @AkashTripathi... I think that this is because you use the uname from the session to load the image, so it has uname store in the session when the user is logged in. But the uname is null when you try to access it with another user. Please check what the code: String UNAME= (String)session.getAttribute("uname"); return when the image is not loaded.

Comment: @fmodos... well, the uname is stored in the session variable as he fills in the registration form, which is the preceding step of image uploading. and, i found one solution for the "image not displaying at the registration time"..well, i've been trying to upload images that were bigger than 500k, bt when i tried it with an image smaller than 100k, it seems to work fine....hence, wat i think is the image is nt "processed" and it needs time..
so wat do u suggest...should i try the image compression option?? can u please suggest a code fr that??

Comment: First make sure that it's because of the size the image, if yes only show the next page when the upload is finished. For what I know it's not possible to compress the image before upload using only the html upload component. I would suggestion you to create a new post in stackoverflow about it.

Comment: ok thanks @fmodos...actually the page redirects to the next page only when the upload finishes, the problem is only during the retrieval at first time \...after the registration, when he logs in, it works fine...
and yeah, i'll try to make a new post. :)